# Требовало заполнения поля, если другие поля заполнены текстом

Tags: html, jquery

Помогите с задачей. 
Нужно чтобы  когда letterNum – не пустое значение и letterDate – также не пустое и type=3, cause=22,31,32 и causeNote=0.

Суть в том, чтобы требовало заполнение поля causeNote.

Как прописать чтобы в letterNum и letterDate были не пустые поля, т.е. заполненные символами. Я поставил  !=, но так не работает.

```
 else if($('#letterNum').val() != 0 && $('#letterDate').val() != 0 && $('#type').val() == 3 && 
                                  $('#cause').val() == 22 || 
                                  $('#cause').val() == 31 ||
                                  $('#cause').val() == 32 
                                  && $('#causeNote').val() == 0){
        $('.errorrep').append('<h3>Поле "Краткое содержание" обязательно для заполнения</h3>');
        $('.errorrep').css({'display':'block'});
        $('#draggable').animate({
            scrollTop:  0
        });
        return false;
    }
```

HTML
HTML

```
<p>
<label for="letterNum">Номер письма</label>
<input id="letterNum" name="letterNum" type="text" value="">
<label for="letterDate">Дата письма</label>
<input id="letterDate" name="letterDate" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
</p>
...
<select id="type" name="typeId" onchange="document.getElementById('typeWarning').hidden = true;"><option value="0"></option><option value="1">
Жалоба</option><option value="2">Заявление</option><option value="3">Консультация</option><option value="4">Предложение</option></select>
...
<select id="cause" name="causeId" onchange="document.getElementById('causeWarning').hidden = true;"><option value="0"></option><option value="22">4.1 ОБ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИИ </option><option value="31">4.10 ОБ ОТКАЗЕ</option><option value="32">4.11 О ПОЛУЧЕНИИ </option></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if($('#letterNum').val() && $('#letterDate').val() && $('#type').val() == 3 && 
        ["22", "31", "32"].indexOf($('#cause')) != -1 && !$('#causeNote').val()) {
```

Comment: Большое спасибо